# JavaFX: Change cursor in Textarea

Tags: java, javafx, cursor, textarea

I have a Textarea which I use to output status logs. I dont want the user to be able to put text in it, so i set editable to false. I also want the cursor to be the normal arrow-cursor, but that doesnt work.

I tried to set the cursor of the textarea but this did not work.

```java
textArea.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
```

It still shows the usual text area cursor when hovering the text area and not the standard arrow cursor. What am I missing?

Comment: Try setMouseTransparent(true).If true, this node (together with all its children) is completely transparent to mouse events.

Comment: Or check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25630584/2244676

Comment: Problem with setMouseTransparent(true) is, that then scrolling is not possible aswell. The other answer helps me understand why my solution does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the solution doesn't work is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25630584/2244676).
If CSS is not the option for you try this approach:

```java
textArea.setId("idTextArea");// you can set also control id in fxml file
textArea.getScene().lookup("#idTextArea .content").setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
```

Make sure that Scene object is initialized before running the code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For some reason I get a Nullpointerexception even when I run this code as last statement. But it worked now if i wait in a seperate thread until the scene is initialized. And after this I have to wait again until textArea.getScene().lookup("#idTextArea .content") is not null.

Probably I should learn about the timing in JavaFX.

Comment: Lookup is not guaranteed to work until CSS has been applied to the scene so you need to invoke the code after WindowEvent.WINDOW_SHOWN event is generating. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16921731/2244676

In your case I guess the more reliable solution is editing external CSS file.

Comment: None of the options worked for me. The Cursor only shows up in textArea borders, but not in content area.